# How to keep the same jump height in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I'm developing a 2D video game using libgdx. I ran into a problem when I try to make jumping a body. 
It does not jump as expected after making it moving to the right.(I can only move to the right or Jump)

If the body jumps before it's moving to the right everything goes fine. But If I decide to make jumping the body after moving it to the right. The body no longer jumps to the same height (It jumps less high). And I don't figure out why..

My method to jump the body :

```
    if (player.isPlayerOnGround()) {
        body.applyForceToCenter(0, 200, true);
    }
```

My method to move the body right

```
    if (player.isPlayerOnGround()) {
        body.setLinearDamping(0f);
        body.setLinearVelocity(1f,0f);
        isMoving = true;
    }
```

My method to stop the body moving right :

```
    body.setLinearDamping(5f);
    isMoving = false;
```

The world use a -9.81f gravity and the body 1f for the Mass.

P.S : Sorry for me bad english, it's not my native language.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing: never use forces to jump. Force has different effects based on how long that force acted. Second: don't use linearDamping. It makes your physics floaty and not real. You could use impulse instead of force in jumping method (it doesn't work very well actually). I'm using this method and it works perfectly

```
    public void jump() {
        if (jumpDelta >= Constants.PLAYER_JUMP_RATE) {
            grounded = level.getContactListener().numFootContacts > 0;
            if (grounded) {
                body.setLinearVelocity(body.getLinearVelocity().x, 7);
                jumpDelta = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Where `if (jumpDelta >= Constants.PLAYER_JUMP_RATE)` prevents from too fast jumping (like two or more jumps at once), `grounded = level.getContactListener().numFootContacts > 0;` checks if player is on platform and finally this `body.setLinearVelocity(body.getLinearVelocity().x, 7);` changes body's vertical velocity. Changing velocity works better than applying impulse because impulse doesn't set velocity, it increases velocity. So if player was moving down with vertical velocity -3 m/s then its velocity will become 4, not 7 as we wanted.

P.S. Instead of linear damping i use this method

```
    public void stopMoving() {
        if (grounded) {
            if (Math.abs(body.getLinearVelocity().x) <= 0.5f)
                body.setLinearVelocity(0, body.getLinearVelocity().y);
            else
                body.applyLinearImpulse(-direction * 0.5f, 0,
                        body.getPosition().x, body.getPosition().y, true);
        } else if (Math.abs(body.getLinearVelocity().x) <= 0.1f)
            body.setLinearVelocity(0, body.getLinearVelocity().y);
        else
            body.applyLinearImpulse(-direction * 0.1f, 0, body.getPosition().x,
                    body.getPosition().y, true);
    }
```

This method can seem too complex but it's really simple. First part handles body's movement on ground and second in the air. if-statements prevent from changing body's direction while stopping and `direction` variable can be 1 if body's moving right, -1 if body's moving left and 0 if body isn't moving.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand what you told me and it works perfectly. But would you mind to telling me how did you learn libgdx ? by your own or did you read a tuto ? Thank you

Comment: Very nice book "Learning Libgdx Game Development" https://www.packtpub.com/game-development/learning-libgdx-game-development I downloaded this book from torrent (piracy, arrrgghh). And then googled my questions. At the end of the book there is some information about box2d to create carrot rain. And i learned box2d reading great official manual (all code is in C++ but you'll untderstand it) and a lot of googling.