# Make a player jump to specific height in LIBGDX

Tags: button, user-controls, libgdx

I want to implement a jump in LIBGDX on clicking buttons in LIBGDX. Everything goes fine but on clicking the button continuously the player keeps on going high .If I didn't release my button its going beyond the screen height . So, I want the player to jump only certain height on each button click and though the button is clicked continuously I want the player to go only certain height and not go beyond the screen. 
    Here is my code,

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          if (buttonup.isPressed()) {
                    if (Gdx.input.isTouched(i)) {
                        gamehero.heroBody.setLinearVelocity(0, 1f);
                        Gdx.app.log("up is presd", "");
                    }
                }
         if (buttonright.isPressed()) {
                if (Gdx.input.isTouched(i)) {


                    gamehero.heroBody.setLinearVelocity(1.2f, 0);
                }
            }
        }
```

On executing this code, the game works just like FLAPPY BIRD. But I want to reach only certain height .  I have tried various methods and referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26831389/how-to-keep-the-same-jump-height-in-libgdx) stack answer too but nothing helped I tired limiting the height using this.gamehero.heroBody.getLinearVelocity().y >= -1 too but didn't work . Please help . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Implement `InputListener` for a class and call:

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(thatClass);
```

Then override `keyUp` in `thatClass` like this:

```
    @Override
    public boolean keyUp (int keycode) {
       if (keycode == Keys.SPACE) {
             //code that make your bird jump
       }
    }
```

This will make your jump code runs only once. If you don't wan't double jumps add a boolean member `alreadyJumping` and set it true when the jump starts and set it false when the jump is ended.

```
@Override
        public boolean keyUp (int keycode) {
           if (keycode == Keys.SPACE && !alreadyJumping) {
                 alreadyJumping = true;
                 //code that make your bird jump
           }
        }
```

If you want your jump to slow down and you character fall decrease you velocity based on `deltaTime` when you render your game.

Comment: It doesn't work as expected because, the player is moving up[ only on first button click ans nothing happens from the next click but I want to move up each time when the button is clicked and even when the button is pressed continuously it must go only certain height @gaRos